# Is there a shell command to get ros distro?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there something I can run in the shell to get something like: "ros-kinetic" or "ros-lunar", depends on what distro I have? "

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284146/is-there-a-shell-command-to-get-ros-distro?/) by [auzn](https://answers.ros.org/users/33414/auzn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=command+line+get+ros+version) gives me #q33769. The more recent of the two answers there show that if you want to see which distro is in use (Indigo and later), run

```
rosversion -d
```

otherwise run

```
rosversion ros
```

to see the version for pre-Indigo (for me this command returns `<unversioned>`, I'm using Indigo).

---

**Edit:**

as @gvdhoorn pointed out in the comments

> Additionally, after `source`ing the right `setup.bash`, the `ROS_DISTRO` environment variable should be set.

Which means that you can get the ROS distribution with

```
echo $ROS_DISTRO
```

as well

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-02**:
Additionally, after `source`ing the right `setup.bash`, the `ROS_DISTRO` environment variable should be set.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-03-02**:\

> A quick Google search gives me #q284146.

That's recursive ;)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-03-02**:
Indeed, probably from the wrong tab instead of #q33769

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-02**:
@130s and @tfoote good catch. Missed that.

**Comment by [auzn](https://answers.ros.org/users/33414/auzn/) on 2018-03-03**:
rosversion -d is what I am looking for